# Efficient search algorithms to calculate crosssection on set of linesegments

Tags: algorithm, search, geometry, line

I have a large dataset of linesegments. Each linesegment consists of `[x-start,x-end]`. I'm searching for an efficient algorithms to calculate for a given x position the set of intersecting lines.

[image]

Comment: Homework in Computational Geometry?

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Actually not. I'm trying to layout a git commit graph in javascript. The linesegments are the branch arrows (i.e. think of git log --graph).

Comment: The *interval tree* is your best friend.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Perfect, that what I searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by yves-daoust: Interval tree is your best friend

Answer (score -1):

1. Find all lines where x ∈ [start; end] in O(n)
2. In found list of lines find the line with minimum start and the line with maximum end (in linear time). So you will have two points (A,B)
3. Find all lines where:

   - A ∈ [start; end]
   - B ∈ [start; end]
   - start ∈ [A; B] and end ∈ [A, B]
     and put them into Set.

Overall time complexity should be O(n)

Comment: Yves Daoust already gave the answer to use an interval tree. Linear search is not an option with 1mil segments and  a lot of queries

Comment: @Konrad Eisele Note that you have not mentioned "a lot of queries" ;)